# php - Dynamically choosing an object's property?

Tags: php, object

I'm trying to dynamically select a property from an object, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

```
$prop = '12345';
$object->$prop
```

in effect trying to recreate this:

```
$object->12345
```

Comment: what is the question here? You have answered your question `$object->$pro` is the correct way of doing it

Comment: the above code should work

Comment: @Guns LOL really? Outsmarted myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the curly braces if you want to access that way..

```
$myobject = new stdClass;
$prop = '12345';
$myobject->$prop = $prop;
echo $myobject->{12345}; //"prints" 12345
```

or simply `echo $myobject->$prop` will do.

If you access it as `echo $myobject->12345;`, below error will be thrown.

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '12345' (T_LNUMBER),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'